# What should I call one that stores?

Tags: single-word-requests

By looking at Oxford's Dictionary, the definition of Storage is pretty straight-forward:

> The action or method of storing something for future use.

But it confuses me on some aspects, for example

> Cooper had put much of the furniture into storage

That means that Cooper **stored** furniture, and that's ok.

---

If Cooper's responsibility is always to store, what does this make him? I thought of the words **Storager** or **Storer**, but couldn't find a definition for either of those in a dictionary, and I don't actually know if the nomenclature is correct.

So, for a phrase like

> Cooper stores furniture very well, he's a really good **...**

**What should I call Cooper?**

Comment: Maybe you need [some](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/storer)—[any](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/storer)?—[different](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/storer) [dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/storer). Because I'm not having a hard time finding "storer" in dictionaries.

Comment: Storeman? [See definition 2](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/storeman).

Comment: @Laurel That's strange, I googled it and found nothing. Afterwards I tried to go straight to the Oxford Dictionary and didn't find it.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! Would you bring it to an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Storer* should do it, as at https://www.google.co.uk/search?rlz=1C5CHFA_enGB718GB718&q=surname+storer&spell=1&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj9wo_v5PLWAhXB1RoKHdPaAdIQvwUIIygA&biw=762&bih=613 but that's old-fashoined, if not archaic.

*Storeman* should be what you want. That tends to be less common in civilian than military life, but a storeman's function is to take things into store and care for the items in his charge until issued out again.

*Warehouseman* might help, also, but I tend to think of a warehouse as being for the shorter term.